# How to access swift resources in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, methods

I want to show the chart in ViewController file.I am able to show the chart in swift file.my problem is, i Want to access that view in viewController file.But am not able to access.I can able to call the method test() from viewController but not able to call setChart() method.This is my Source Code:

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ChartsDemo-swift.h"
#import "ChartsDemo-Bridging-Header.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //View Creation
    UIView *mainView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 270)];

    //Array Creation
    NSMutableArray *mn = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"5",@"8", nil];
    NSArray *un = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"6",@"10", nil];

    //Instance for Swift Class
    BarChartViewController *bcv = [[BarChartViewController alloc]init];

    //Function Call
    [bcv test];
    [bcv setChart:mn values:un];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning 
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

BarChartViewController.swift

```
import Foundation
import Charts

class BarChartViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var barChartView: BarChartView!
var months: [String]!

override func viewDidLoad()
{

    //Array Creation
     months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    let units = [20.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0, 12.0, 16.0, 4.0, 18.0, 2.0, 4.0, 5.0, 4.0]

   //Function call
    setChart(months, values: units)
    piesetChart(months, values: units)

}

func test()
{
    print("hi")
}


func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double])
{

    var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []

    for var i=0; i < dataPoints.count; i++
    {
        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")
    let chartData = BarChartData(xVals: months, dataSet: chartDataSet)

    chartDataSet.colors = [UIColor .redColor()]

    barChartView.data = chartData
    barChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .Bottom
}
```

1.How to access the swift view in Objective c view?

2.How to access the setChart method from ViewController.m?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u want to access the `setChart()` method from your `ViewController.m` means,

1. Import the `Bridging-Header.h` in `ViewController.m`
2. Create an instance for the `BarChartViewController.swift` from the `ViewController` class. By using the instance you can access the `setChart()` method.